# Why Mongo query for null filters in FETCH after performing IXSCAN

Tags: mongodb, null, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes, query-planner

According to [Mongo Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/),

> The `{ item : null }` query matches documents that either contain the
>   `item` field whose value is `null` or that do not contain the `item`
>   field.

I can't find documentation for this, but as far as I can tell, both cases (value is `null` or field is missing) are stored in the index as `null`.

So if I do `db.orders.createIndex({item: 1})` and then `db.orders.find({item: null})`, I would expect an `IXSCAN` to find all documents that either contain the `item` field whose value is `null` or that do not contain the `item` field, and only those documents.

So then why does `db.orders.find({item: null}).explain()` perform `filter: {item: {$eq: null}}` in the `FETCH` stage after it performs an `IXSCAN`?  What possible documents could need to be filtered out?

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "temp.orders",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "item" : {
                "$eq" : null
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "item" : {
                    "$eq" : null
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "item" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "item_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "item" : [
                        "[null, null]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Andys-MacBook-Pro-2.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.8",
        "gitVersion" : "ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I thought maybe `undefined` values would get indexed as `null`, but simple experimentation rules this out:

```
> db.orders.createIndex({item: 1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.orders.insert({item: undefined})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.orders.find({item: {$type: 6}}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "temp.orders",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "item" : {
                "$type" : 6
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "item" : {
                    "$type" : 6
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "item" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "item_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "item" : [
                        "[undefined, undefined]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Andys-MacBook-Pro-2.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.8",
        "gitVersion" : "ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics for a null equality match predicate (e.g. `{"a.b": null}`) are complicated enough because a field could contain subdocuments that an index scan alone isn't enough to provide the correct result.

According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18653?focusedCommentId=931817&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-931817,

> Version 2.6.0 of the server changed the semantics of a null equality
>   match predicate, such that the document {a: []} was no longer
>   considered a match for the query predicate {"a.b": null} (in prior
>   versions of the server, this document was considered a match for this
>   predicate). This is documented in the 2.6 compatibility notes, under
>   the "null comparison" section.
>
> For an index with key pattern {"a.b": 1}, this document {a: []}
>   generates the index key {"": null}. Other documents like {a: null} and
>   the empty document {} also generate the index key {"": null}. As a
>   result, if a query with predicate {"a.b": null} uses this index, the
>   query system cannot tell just from the index key {"": null} whether or
>   not the associated document matches the predicate. As a result,
>   INEXACT_FETCH bounds are assigned instead of EXACT bounds, and hence a
>   FETCH stage is added to the query execution tree.

Additional explanation:

> 1. The document {} generates the index key {"": null} for the index with key pattern {"a.b": 1}.
> 2. The document {a: []} also generates the index key {"": null} for the index with key pattern {"a.b": 1}.
> 3. The document {} matches the query {"a.b": null}.
> 4. The document {a: []} does not match the query {"a.b": null}.
>
> Therefore, a query {"a.b": null} that is answered by an index with key
>   pattern {"a.b": 1} must fetch the document and re-check the predicate,
>   in order to ensure that the document {} is included in the result set
>   and that the document {a: []} is not included in the result set.