# Null value in $all condition triggers COLLSCAN instead of IXSCAN in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some collection in mongodb (version 3.6.12) with an index on the `my_array` field.

The explanation for the query: `{ my_array: {$all: ["foo"]} }` tells me that the index (IXSCAN) on the `my_array` field is used - as expected.

But using `null` as a value in the query (`{ my_array: {$all: [null]} }`) will trigger a collection scan (COLLSCAN) instead - which kills the performance.

Is there some explanation why there's no index scan when using `null` as a value in an `$all` condition? Or may this be a bug in mongo?

Comment: James, verify the link bellow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830323/why-mongo-query-for-null-filters-in-fetch-after-performing-ixscan

Comment: Thanks for the link. The explanation there seem to explain my case as well.